# Intercepting ng-click in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

is it possible to write an interceptor for ng-click?
I have a button or a link that leads to a deletion of an object in the backend. I'd like to have a confirmation dialog (modal) by just adding an attribute to the button/link. E.g.:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="deleteIt(id)" confirmation-needed>Delete</a>
```

Is this possible with AngularJS? Is there a better approach do solve this issue?

**EDIT** The deleteIt method resides in different controllers.

Thx

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I've put an example directive in:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GJwK7ldGa9LY90bMuOfl?p=preview

I achieve it by creating a directive:

1. with a higher `priority` than `ngClick`, so that it gets called before `ngClick`,
2. making that `terminal` so that it doesn't call `ngClick`.
3. listening to click events, and then evaluating the `ngClick` value if the message is ok.

As a bonus, you can pass in your own message, such as:

```html
<a href="#" ng-click="deleteIt(id)" 
    confirmation-needed="Really Delete?"
        >Delete with custom message</a>
```

The code looks like this:

```js
app.directive('confirmationNeeded', function () {
  return {
    priority: 1,
    terminal: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      var msg = attr.confirmationNeeded || "Are you sure?";
      var clickAction = attr.ngClick;
      element.bind('click',function () {
        if ( window.confirm(msg) ) {
          scope.$eval(clickAction)
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: This is close how I would have done it too.. But, here is another plunk that works pretty much the same except it doesnt care whether you have an ng-click or not.. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Cwu15Z8U6ok0MMF8p6Ks?p=preview

Comment: @ganaraj: That doesn't work when I click Cancel, because JQLite's `createEventHandler` continues to iterate through all events bound, and doesn't stop the second `bind('click',...)` from being called. (My browser: Chrome Version 26.0.1410.65 on Mac OSX 10.6.8)

Comment: This ALSO prevents all other directives from working, i.e. if you add an ng-show to the same tag...

Comment: @samson Agreed - elegant solution but creates other problems. I ended up using an isolated scope with a custom '&' binding.

Comment: @georgiosd I've posted my approach below, which is similar to this one, but (I think) much simpler.

Comment: I've posted another answer below that allows you to keep ng-click functionality and your own scope (without going terminal).

Answer (score 10):

I've given up on getting Piran's answer to work as I'd like it to. Instead, I've started just replacing ngClick with my own directive:

```
.directive('confirmClick', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elt, attrs) {
            elt.bind('click', function(e) {
                var message = attrs.confirmation || "Are you sure you want to do that?";
                if (window.confirm(message)) {
                    var action = attrs.confirmClick;
                    if (action)
                        scope.$apply(scope.$eval(action));
                }
            });
        },
    };
})
```

This directive doesn't even have its own scope, which simplifies combining it with other directives significantly. It takes everything it needs directly from the `attrs`. It's used like so:

```
<span ng-show="editing" confirm-click="delete()" confirmation="delete confirmation message goes here">some text</span>
```

The `delete()` function must exist somewhere higher up in the `$scope` chain. I'm sure this could be improved by taking a closer look at how `ng-click` is implemented, but I haven't gotten around to it yet!

Comment: Is the $apply($eval()) still needed? Seems to work just fine with just $apply(action).

Comment: Hmm... It's been a while since I wrote this... I guess you don't need both!

Answer (score 5):

I played with this for a long time, but the async nature of Angular makes it tough to count on every directive playing nicely together.  Then, I saw @tosh's answer, which got me thinking.

I think this combines several advantages: **Create a Directive and Prepend ngClick**

So, just add this directive to your app, and then add the "confirm-click" attribute to your link, as well as the confirmClick() function to your ngClick.

Link:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="confirmClick() && deleteIt(id)" confirm-click>Delete</a>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('confirmClick', function() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // setup a confirmation action on the scope
            scope.confirmClick = function(msg) {
                // msg can be passed directly to confirmClick('are you sure?') in ng-click
                // or through the confirm-click attribute on the <a confirm-click="Are you sure?"></a>
                msg = msg || attrs.confirmClick || 'Are you sure?';
                // return true/false to continue/stop the ng-click
                return confirm(msg);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This is very similar to injecting the standard confirm() dialog, but because you have it in a directive, you can customize how you choose to run your confirm dialog (maybe a pretty modal, instead of a window dialog).

**** BONUS ANSWER ****

I played with this more and integrated a solution that uses a modal window as the confirmation, rather than the default window.  Here's the complete solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23718694/1135826

Answer (score 3):

You can inject `$window` into your controller so that you can use `$window.confirm` from
your scope, then:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="confirm('message') && deleteIt(id)">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, @tosh!  This put me on the right track for what I needed to do.  I posted another answer below that takes the same concept but couples it with a directive, so I can customize my confirm dialog.