# Custom delete confirm in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app with a list of items. Im trying to implement a custom "Confirm Delete" modal, so that when the user clicks the "Delete" button beside an item, the modal open to confirm deletion. On clicking "Yes", a deleteItem() function is triggered. My problem is that the server is returning 404 not found for the delete request. It works when I use the standard jquery confirm dialog, so I'm guessing the item ID isn't getting passed through the modal to the delete function. can anyone help?

```
   <div class="span6">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="min-width: 80px;">Name:</th>
                <th style="width:20px;"> </th>
                <th style="width:20px;"> </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>


                <td><a ng-click="editItem(item.id)" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a ng-click="openModal(item.id)" class="btn btn-small btn-success">Delete</a></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

          <modal-dialog show='modalShown' id = "itemModal" width='300px' height='40%'>
                  <p>Are you sure you want to delete this item?<p>
                      <button ng-click = "deleteItem(item.id)" class = "link">Yes</button>
          </modal-dialog>

    </div>
```

Here's the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope', 'ItemsFactory', 'ItemFactory', '$location', '$route',
        function ($scope, ItemsFactory, ItemFactory, $location, $route) {

             $scope.modalShown = false;

         //callback for ng-click 'deleteItem':

            $scope.openModal = function (itemId) {
                $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;

            };

        //callback for ng-click 'deleteItem':

            $scope.deleteItem = function (itemId) {

                ItemFactory.delete({ id: itemId }).$promise.then(function (items){
                    $scope.items = items;
                    $location.path('/items'); 
                    $route.reload();
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });    

                // } 

            };
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602222/create-a-simple-bootstrap-yes-no-confirmation-or-just-notification-alert-in-angu/37265529#37265529

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `item` is only "known" inside the scope created by the `ngRepeat` for each element.
`<modal-dialog>` is not inside that scope and has no knowledge about `item`.

You could refactor the code like this:

```
// In HTML:
<modal-dialog ...>
    ...
    <button ng-click="deleteItem()" ...

// In controller:
$scope.modalShown = false;
$scope.itemToDeleteId;
...
$scope.openModal = function (itemId) {
    $scope.itemToDeleteId = itemId;
    $scope.modalShown = true;
};
...
$scope.deleteItem = function () {
    if (!$scope.itemToDeleteId) { return; }
    var itemId = $scope.itemToDeleteId;
    $scope.itemToDeleteId = null;
    ...
```

Answer (score 18):

I've spent some time on this, but I wanted to do it all in one click (like a regular window confirm dialog).  It started with the question "[How do I intercept ng-click in angularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23707501/1135826)"

I developed a directive and service that work with the UI Bootstrap Modal to create a modal dialog that confirms an ng-click action before proceeding.

[Demo on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WcLUuXMpd6djYmvVBBIN?p=preview) or here:

```
/*
 Confirm an ng-click action with a modal dialog window (requires UI Bootstrap Modal service)
 Using this modal requires two things: apply the attribute to the dom element and prepend
 the confirmClick() action to the ng-click attribute.

    <a href="#" ng-click="confirmClick() && deleteItem(item)" confirm-click>Delete</a>

 */
.directive('confirmClick', ['$q', 'dialogModal', function($q, dialogModal) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // ngClick won't wait for our modal confirmation window to resolve,
            // so we will grab the other values in the ngClick attribute, which
            // will continue after the modal resolves.
            // modify the confirmClick() action so we don't perform it again
            // looks for either confirmClick() or confirmClick('are you sure?')
            var ngClick = attrs.ngClick.replace('confirmClick()', 'true')
                .replace('confirmClick(', 'confirmClick(true,');

            // setup a confirmation action on the scope
            scope.confirmClick = function(msg) {
                // if the msg was set to true, then return it (this is a workaround to make our dialog work)
                if (msg===true) {
                    return true;
                }
                // msg can be passed directly to confirmClick('are you sure?') in ng-click
                // or through the confirm-click attribute on the <a confirm-click="Are you sure?"></a>
                msg = msg || attrs.confirmClick || 'Are you sure?';
                // open a dialog modal, and then continue ngClick actions if it's confirmed
                dialogModal(msg).result.then(function() {
                    scope.$eval(ngClick);
                });
                // return false to stop the current ng-click flow and wait for our modal answer
                return false;
            };
        }
    }
}])

/*
 Open a modal confirmation dialog window with the UI Bootstrap Modal service.
 This is a basic modal that can display a message with okay or cancel buttons.
 It returns a promise that is resolved or rejected based on okay/cancel clicks.
 The following settings can be passed:

    message         the message to pass to the modal body
    title           (optional) title for modal window
    okButton        text for OK button. set false to not include button
    cancelButton    text for Cancel button. ste false to not include button

 */
.service('dialogModal', ['$modal', function($modal) {
    return function (message, title, okButton, cancelButton) {
        // setup default values for buttons
        // if a button value is set to false, then that button won't be included
        okButton = okButton===false ? false : (okButton || 'Confirm');
        cancelButton = cancelButton===false ? false : (cancelButton || 'Cancel');

        // setup the Controller to watch the click
        var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, settings) {
            // add settings to scope
            angular.extend($scope, settings);
            // ok button clicked
            $scope.ok = function () {
                $modalInstance.close(true);
            };
            // cancel button clicked
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        };

        // open modal and return the instance (which will resolve the promise on ok/cancel clicks)
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template: '<div class="dialog-modal"> \
                <div class="modal-header" ng-show="modalTitle"> \
                    <h3 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h3> \
                </div> \
                <div class="modal-body">{{modalBody}}</div> \
                <div class="modal-footer"> \
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()" ng-show="okButton">{{okButton}}</button> \
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()" ng-show="cancelButton">{{cancelButton}}</button> \
                </div> \
            </div>',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                settings: function() {
                    return {
                        modalTitle: title,
                        modalBody: message,
                        okButton: okButton,
                        cancelButton: cancelButton
                    };
                }
            }
        });
        // return the modal instance
        return modalInstance;
    }
}])
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic!

Comment: @dustin Could you please tell me how to delete with the id rather than index of it. if there will be an id for every item. i am using http.delete to delete rather than splice

Comment: @codelearner, my particular example is only about how to intercept the click action to prompt with a confirmation. in this example, you could customize the "deleteItem(item)" method to do whatever you wanted. it will fire whatever the second action is, if the confirmClick() method is confirmed.

Comment: For the new version, you have to rename `$modal` -> `$uibModal` and `$modalInstance` -> `$uibModalInstance`

Answer (score 0):

A custom directive:

```
/**
 * A generic confirmation for risky actions.
 * Usage: Add attributes: ng-really-message="Really?" ng-really-click="takeAction()" function
 */
angular.module('app').directive('ngReallyClick', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                var message = attrs.ngReallyMessage;
                if (message && confirm(message)) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.ngReallyClick);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: so in this way how would you change the style of the confirm box?