# directive for confirmation on delete button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using this directive for confirmation on delete button. But either i click cancel or yes it deletes the app.

```
<small class="btn" ng-click="delete_app(app.app_id)" ng-show="app.app_id" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure you want to delete this app? You will loose all data and metrics associated with this app."> Delete </small>

.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
    function(){
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure you want to delete this app? You will loose all data and metrics associated with this app.";
                var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
                element.bind('click',function (event) {
                    if ( window.confirm(msg) ) {
                        scope.$eval(clickAction)
                    }
                });
            }
        };
}])
```

Comment: give complete information, paste your html code also!

Comment: A fiddle would help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/njpL0ecn/1/

Comment: Your ng-click would be executing anyway. I think that's the problem.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for me.

Comment: yes@ hasH , how can i avoid it ?  
@boyD - I'm using fiddle for first time, may be something is wrong.

Comment: Duplicate with great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23718694/289545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing seems to be wrong in your directive code.
You can write html like below. 
Of course your controller needs to have the method named 'test' to be called.

```
<button ng-confirm-click confirmed-click="test()">Test</button>
```

If you click 'cancel' button on confirming dialog, the method would not be called properly.